# Flutter Error: "Bluetooth permission missing in manifest" on Android 12

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I was adding some Bluetooth permission in manifest like Android Developer said in "https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions". but, why I still get this error? or I forgot a code to add? or what? I was so confused about this. I just got this problem in android 12.

I also searched  some references, but they says same like "add some Bluetooth permission in manifest", but I am still getting error :(.

Manifest:

[image]

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the app?

Comment: yeah, I was try to rebuild my app, clean & get, restart IDE & emulator/device, but still get same problem :)

Comment: Not sure from what you posted, but it seems that you used both the pre-12 way and the current way to define permissions, is that right? You should use only one of them.

Comment: @zerozuro did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem. I'm using the package permission_handler.

Comment: Anyone has fixed this issue? I'm still struggling with this using permissions_handler: 11.0.1

Comment: this is work on me. i use permission_handler: 11.0.0 and just write 

"PermissionStatus status = await Permission.bluetoothConnect.status;"

and add this to manifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Answer (score 0):

After making changes in the **Android Manifest** you should:

1. Stop the App
2. Open the terminal in the location of your app (inside the IDE) and call:
   `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get`.
3. After that, run the project and your problem should be gone.

Comment: I was try it,
 but, nothing has changed